# Exclude HTML tag with Nokogiri

Tags: html, ruby, nokogiri

I am trying to get all the text in TD tag except what is inside `<strong>` tags (there might be any number of them).

In this example I want to get: "`graavis ● diakriitik (`) ↝`" and "`acute accent`":

```
<tr class="level2">
    <td> 
        <strong> grave accent </strong> 
         <strong> (=backquote character) </strong>
         graavis ● diakriitik (`) ↝ 
         <a href="?word=sv82">acute accent</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I'm trying to use the code below, but it doesn't work:

```
desc = page.css('tr td:not(strong)').text
```

Comment: `@doc.xpath('//tr/td/node()[not(self::strong)]')`

Comment: @Bala `strong` is a tag, not an attribute of `td`.

Comment: @mudasobwa: you are right. Removed it. Your solution works perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider:

```
page.search("strong").remove
page.css(".level2 > td").text.strip
```

Comment: Did you consider a scenario where a normal text has a word "strong" in it?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't matter if text has the word _strong_. The `search` method is actually searching for `CSS selectors`.